Unable to open new html page once authenticated using json web tokens
I'm following this article https://medium.com/@favalcodes/authentication-and-authorization-in-node-js-15142e33f1d7.
I'm using json web tokens to authenticate users. The server.js code is below.
I've debugged the code and it's hitting the app.get('\profile, authenticateToken....) function and authenticates the user when they log in but the issue I have is that it doesn't seem to be triggering
res.sendFile(`${base}/profile.html`); 

and it's not loading up the profile.html page.
I think the reason is because when I make the get request from the client login.js file it is expecting something to come back. So for example in login.js I have an ajax request:
login.js
 $.ajax({
          url: '/profile',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
          },
          success: function(response) {
                       
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 401 || jqXHR.status === 403) {
                 alert('Access denied');
              } else {
                 alert('An error occurred: ' + textStatus);
             }
          }
     });

And so when performing the get request, when the user is successfully authenticated it is coming back to "success" here and not loading up the profile.html page from server.js
server.js
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();
const secretKey = 'secretKey'; //You can use anything here as your secret key

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // Authenticate user
  const user = { id: 1, username: 'example' };
  const token = jwt.sign(user, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
  res.json({ token });
});

//This is a function to authenticate the token if it's a valid token
//This function serves as a middleware
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

  jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
}

// This route authorizes the user if the token used is valid
app.get('/profile', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
  try {
      res.sendFile(`${base}/profile.html`);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
  }
});

For html pages that don't need authentication, eg. for an "About Us" page, I can just use windows.location.href or just href and then hit the server with
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${base}/about.html`);
});

And that seems to load the page - but when authenticating, it doesn't send the page back.
My question is, I have the server code and it does the authentication, but how do I trigger the app.get('profile', authenticateToken....) from the client and send back the profile.html page?
Thanks.

You are correct that it is expecting something to come back, you cannot call a specific route in express that returns or redirects to a page using ajax. In your case, you should directly redirect the user to the profile.html page inside the success function:
success: function(response) {
    window.location.href = 'profile.html';
}

Otherwise, instead of using an ajax function for logging in you can simply use a post form to /login and inside the express login function add res.redirect('/profile')

That's where I'm a bit confused. Because if window.location.href can load up the profile.html page - then someone can just type in profile.html in the browser and load up that page. Obviously it won't be profile.html for a specific user because the login won't have been authenticated, but it's not exactly the kind of authentication I was hoping for. I liked the idea of using express with authenticateToken as the second parameter for the specific page you won't to load up - but just not sure how to actually load the page. Thx
